# How can one get a correct jQuery offset() for a an img that is has css zoom applied to it in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, zooming

I am trying to apply a css zoom effect on an img and when I do the jQuery function offset() seems to return the wrong value.

I have created a little [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hqLnJ/4/) of my problem that shows the issue I am having. Please check this out in Chrome because that is the browser I am experiencing this problem in (I don't think

If you click on the show frog offset button it will show a value of 219 for the offset().left of the frog img, then if you press the zoom button the from will be zoomed by 2.0. If you then press the show frog offset button again, you will see offset().left of 101.5 for the frog img.

Here is the code I use to zoom and unzoom the frog's img in my [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hqLnJ/4/) (also linked above)

```
$("#zoom-frog-button").click(function() {
    $(".frog-img").css("zoom", 2.0);
});

$("#unzoom-frog-button").click(function() {
    $(".frog-img").css("zoom", 1.0);
});
```

Comment: I am not seeing anything wrong in the fiddle. Why do you think it is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be working correct. When you use the zoom styling property, it increases/decreases the size of the element you apply it to. So, when thinking of offset() returning the position relative to the document, this image zooms at a setting of 2, doubling it's size, and in return, cutting it's offset() in half.  The document size isn't changing, but the image is. I think this is what you are thinning is an issue?  Hopefully that helps you! Happy coding!